# Exclude Certain Child Nodes from XPath Result with Single Call to element.getText()?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to extract content matching XPath: `.//*[contains (@class, 'post-content')]` However I wish to exclude child nodes:

**1)** Containing text: P3 or AP

**2)** Div containing id = bottom

**3)** Form containing label with text: Get email updates

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <p>P1</p>
    <p>P2</p>
    <p>P3</p>
    <p>P4</p>
    <p>P5</p>
    <p>AP</p>
    <div id="td-a-rec bottom"> </div>
    <form action="https://example.com/subscribe method=" post " id="subscribe-form " name="subscribe-form " class="validate " target="_blank " novalidate=" ">
        <div id="signup_scroll ">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL ">Get email updates from..</label>
            <input type="email " value=" " name="EMAIL " class="email " id="EMAIL " placeholder="email address " required=" ">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; " aria-hidden="true "><input type="text " name="b_11 " tabindex="-1 " value=" "></div>
            <div class="clear "><input type="submit " value="Subscribe " name="subscribe " id="-subscribe " class="button "></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am able to achieve this by using the `XPath` syntax: `[not(contains(@id,'bottom'))]` + `[not(contains(text(),'P3'))]` + `[not(contains(text(),'AP'))]` etc However, the main issue is that instead of matching all desired child elements as a single element - it now matches each element as a `WebElement List`.

Right now the only way to extract desired text is by iterating through the web element list and concatenating the results into a single S`enter code here`tring.

Is is possible to directly scrape all *desired content* in one shot (with a single call to `element.getText()` ) without the need to iterate through element list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like all you want is the text from the P tags with a couple of exclusions. The CSS selector `div.td-post-content > p` will get you all the P tags including the ones you want to exclude. You can gather those into a list and then remove the text you want to exclude to give you the final list.

```
List<WebElement> ps = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.td-post-content > p"));
List<String> text = ps.stream().map(e -> e.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
text.remove("AP");
text.remove("P3");
System.out.println(text);
```

Running this prints

```
[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5]
```